# Modify text column based on the column before it

Tags: linux, multiple-columns

I have a file whose first 28 rows are just words. Starting from 29th to 100th row, I have position information of atoms for A, B and C, and their 3d coordinates. Now what I would like to do is to change Z (the 4th column) in a way related to Y (the 3rd column) for Row 29-100:

Z = Z + sin(Y/10*Pi). Is that possible just in the terminal? Thanks.

```
A 0.016333 0.003203 0.472723
A 0.016333 0.035228 0.472723
B 0.016333 0.067253 0.472723 
B 0.016333 0.099278 0.472723 
C 0.016333 0.131303 0.472723 
C 0.016333 0.163328 0.472723
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane '$F[3] += sin($F[2]/10 * 4 * atan2 1, 1) if 29 .. 100;
            print "@F"
           ' input_file > output_file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- `-l` adds a newline to `print`
- `4 * atan2 1, 1` is π
- 29 .. 100 is true only for lines in the given range

Comment: I guess F[1] should be F[2]?