# Get variable from shell script in a perl IF statement

Tags: perl, shell, if-statement

This is a follow-up question from [Modify text column based on the column before it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514800/modify-text-column-based-on-the-column-before-it)

I wanna change the starting index of the line processing, say start from the third line. I notice that in order for perl to use the variable in shell, I must export the variable and use `$ENV{}` in perl, see:

```
#!/bin/bash

t=3 
export t 
perl -e 'print $ENV{t}'
perl -lane '$F[3] += sin($F[2]/10 * 4 * atan2 1, 1) if($ENV{t} .. 4);
print "@F" 
'test.txt > test_new.txt
```

Here test.txt is merely the same with the previous question:

```
A 0.016333 0.003203 0.472723
A 0.016333 0.035228 0.472723
B 0.016333 0.067253 0.472723 
B 0.016333 0.099278 0.472723 
C 0.016333 0.131303 0.472723 
C 0.016333 0.163328 0.472723
```

However, the `$ENV{t}` does not work at all: the line processing still starts from the first line. Maybe in IF statement the usage is different??
What should I do to control which line to start?

Comment: try `if ( $. >= $ENV{t} )`

Comment: `if ( $a .. $b )` is always FALSE for any integer values.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html search for `$.` or `INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`

Comment: The construct `TT=123 perl -lane '...... $ENV{TT} ....' foo.txt` will also work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [`range operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) that's doing it. The particular rule you are using for `(3..4)` is

> If either operand of scalar ".." is a constant expression, that operand is considered true if it is equal (== ) to the current input line number (the $. variable).

Otherwise,

> It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again. It doesn't become false till the next time the range operator is evaluated.

When you have a *variable* for one end point it is being evaluated and is found to be true. So the left end is always true and the operator never gets to be false, and all lines are printed.

As for how to do it, forego the elegance and test explicitly,

```
if $. >= $ENV{t} and $. <= 4
```

You can still use the range operator, for a more compact expression

```
if $.==$ENV{t} .. 4
```

However, at this point this may be not as clear as a normal test while a tiny gain in performance (if any) may not even be measurable.  Thanks to [`ikegami`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for bringing this up and for further comments.

Comment: Thanks. but is there a way to control which line to start with?

Comment: @James  I got pulled away from this, but wanted at least to answer the question. I'll add to it in a few mintues.

Comment: I just solved it using $.  It would be great if you know better ways and post them!

Comment: @James  Glad to see you worked it out!  I've also added that to my answer.  What do you consider "better" ways?  More concise or shorter or ....?

Comment: Using the range operator, it would look like `if $.==$ENV{t} .. 4`.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you -- I've had that in my test here. I didn't think it was any "better" ... but it is.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the point of using the range operator either, in this case.

Comment: @ikegami  That's what I was thinking -- but it is more compact and perhaps a tiny bit more efficient (?).  On the other hand it mixes things and a normal test is probably clearer now.

Comment: @James  Having in mind your previous question, is there a reason that this needs to be a bash script? You wanted a one-liner, now it's become a script -- why not Perl? I don't think you can have a really better solution with a one-liner.

Comment: @zdim I agree a one liner of Perl is the best. Actually I have some other stuff going on in the same shell script. So I just added the perl command.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

t=3  
export t  
perl -e 'print $ENV{t}' 
perl -lane '$F[3] += sin($F[2]/10 * 4 * atan2 1, 1) if(($.>=$ENV{t})&&($.<= 4)); 
print "@F" 'test.txt > test_new.txt
```

The above code works! It is great to know the current line number is `$.`

The result is:

```
A 0.016333 0.003203 0.472723
A 0.016333 0.035228 0.472723
B 0.016333 0.067253 0.493849581177725
B 0.016333 0.099278 0.503907047205915
C 0.016333 0.131303 0.472723
C 0.016333 0.163328 0.472723
```